# List [0-1] to binary representation fast

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, matrix, binary

I am trying to convert the rows [0-1] of a matrix to representation in number (binary equivalent), the code I have is the following:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_binary_matrix(matrix):
    result = []
    for i in matrix:
        val = '0b' + ''.join([str(x) for x in i])
        result.append(int(val, 2))
    result = np.array(result)
    return result

initial_matrix = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
result = generate_binary_matrix(initial_matrix )
print(result)
```

This code works but it is very slow, does anyone know how to do it in a faster way?

Comment: Is in python3...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a 0/1 list to binary using just arithmetic, which should be faster:

```
from functools import reduce
b = reduce(lambda r, x: 2*r + x, i)
```

Comment: Try but I don't understand how can I use it?

Comment: You can replace `val = ...; result.append(int(val, 2))` in your code by `result.append(reduce(lambda r, x: 2*r + x, i))`.

Comment: What happens is that the function reduce generates me, as a result, inf, I imagine that this happens because the binaries that I try to generate are extremely large.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know without seeing a reproducible example.

Comment: Hello, I edited the code of the function and added an example.

Comment: My code seems to work fine for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you matrix numpy array is `A` with `m` rows and `n` columns.
Create a `b` vector with `n`elements by:

`b = np.power(2, np.arange(n))[::-1]`

then your answer is `A @ b`

Example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]])
n = A.shape[1]
b = np.power(2, np.arange(n))[::-1]
print(A @ b)  # --> [1 5]
```

update - I reversed b as the MSB (2^n-1) is A[:,0] + power arguments were mistakenly flipped + add an example.

Comment: Try this: 


def generate_binary_matrix(matrix):
  b = np.power(np.arange(len(matrix[0])), 2)
  result_v2 = matrix @ b

but don't get the same result

Comment: Which bit is the lsb? The first element in each row or the last?

Comment: I don't know what the lsb bit is, but let's imagine that the matrix has the following form: [[0,0,1], [1,0,1]] and I want to generate something like this: [b'001, b '101].

Comment: ok. i updated my answer.
LSB = Least Significant Bit
MSB = Most Significant Bit

Comment: Ok, the LSB would be the last and the MSB would be the first, I need a binary representation of an array [0,0,1,0,1] of specific size m to a binary of the same size m b'00101

Comment: Hello, I edited the code of the function and added an example.

Comment: we are getting the same results. what is the gap?